# Why we need to specify cardinality in cognos/hibernate but not in oracle

Tags: oracle10g, cardinality, cognos-8

When we specify a foregin key relationship in oracle, we do not need to say whether relationship is 1 to 1, 1 to many etc. But when we specify a relationship in the cognos framework manager, why we need to specify 1 to 1, 1 to many etc?
Also, unrelated but just curious, the same is the behavior in a ORM tool like Hibernate.
Is the specification only for optmisation purposes?

My other question is what is th effect of specifying a wrong cardinality relationship? i,e, I specify a 1 to 1 relationship where it is actually 1 to many. What is the effect i am risking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *do* declare the relationships in Oracle, the nature of the relationship is implicit in the way that it is declared to Oracle, e.g.:

```
CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES parent_table (id)
```

implies that there is a 1:M relationship between the parent table and this table.

If, in addition, there was a unique constraint on the child table, e.g.:

```
CONSTRAINT uk UNIQUE (id)
```

implies that the relationship is 1:1.

Answer (score 0):

From Cognos documentation:

IBM® Cognos® software uses the cardinality of a relationship in the following ways:

to avoid double-counting fact data 
to support loop joins that are common in star schema models 
to optimize access to the underlying data source system 
to identify query subjects that behave as facts or dimensions

For further details, look here:
[Framework Manager Cardinality](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r1m1/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_best.10.1.1.doc/c_bp-cardinality.html#bp-cardinality)

Comment: Thanks. But how come Oracle does not need this cardinality to be specified when we are creating tables?

Comment: Look at Jeffrey Kemp answer above to understand how you can define 1:M and 1:1.
In any way Oracle is database, and Cognos is BI tool. The way they work or treat relation is quite different.
While in Oracle DB it usually done for referential integrity between tables, in BI tools (such as Cognos), it is done usually to achieve better and right (for correct results) query generation.